# Laravel Eloquent Show Parent and Child Data in Select2

Tags: laravel, eloquent, jquery-select2

I am trying to get parent and child data and show it in Select2.

**Model**

```
// JobTypes model
public function jobs()
{
    // one type of job has many jobs
    return $this->hasMany('App\Jobs', 'id'); // id refer to jobs.id
}

// Jobs model
public function job_types()
{
    // one job only belongs to one type of job
    return $this->belongsTo('App\jobTypes');
}
```

**Controller**

```
$keyword = $this->request->get('q');

    $categories = \App\JobTypes::with(['jobs' => function ($query) use ($keyword) {
        $query
            ->whereHas('job_types')
            ->orWhereDoesntHave('job_types')
            ->where('name', 'LIKE', "%$keyword%");
    }])->get();

    return $categories;
```

**View**

```
$('#goals').select2({
maximumSelectionLength: 2,
ajax: {
    url: '{{ url('showjobs') }}',
    processResults: function(data) {
        return {
           results: data.map(function(item) {
                return {
                    id: item.id, 
                    text: item.name,

                     //childern
                     children: data.map(function(child){
                         return {
                             id: child.id,
                             text: child.name
                         }
                     })
                     // end childern

                } 
            })
        }
    }
} });
```

But the result is not expected.
[image: child data filled with parent data]

So, I want all of child data above coming from 'jobs' table. I've tried many times to solve this problem but still stuck here.

Comment: what error showing after select

Comment: try to check your query again, see what data you are really getting because based on your code in controller your query is wrong

Comment: @Boni no error showing. But the result is not expected. The child data should come from 'jobs' table

Comment: @Kevin Loquencio I already check it many times, but still stuck on it.

Comment: @SeadLab What exactly you are trying to get? a list of job types and also every job types will list also the jobs? is that right?

Comment: Exactly. That's what I mean. You see, the parent is filled by job type, the child is filled by job type as well. It's not supposed like that.